# In the below code, isn’t both the object references is of StringBuilder type?

Tags: java

Consider the following three statements in Java:

1. `StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Boo");`
2. `StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("Boo");`
3. `String s3 = new String ("Boo");`

Why does  `s1.equals(s2)` return `false`?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html): "StringBuilder implements Comparable but does not override equals. Thus, the natural ordering of StringBuilder is inconsistent with equals."

Comment: use toString() for equality check

Answer (score 4):

The StringBuilder class in Java is unlike others wherein it does not override `equals` and `hashcode`.  If you are new to Java, it may not be immediately apparent that if a class does not provide an overriden implementation of `equals`, the system uses the `Object` class' `equals` method, which is no different than comparing the references, aka the memory pointer.

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Boo");
StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder("Boo");
s1.equals(s2) // false
s1.toString().equals(s2.toString()) // true because String overrides equals
s1 = s2
s1.equals(s2) // true because same reference
```

It would be wise to convert the StringBuilder objects to String by using the `toString` method and then comparing it.

EDIT:  Did some googling to understand why `StrintBuilder` & `StringBuffer` does not override `equals` & `hashcode`.  It turns out that the reason is that objects of these classes are expected to be mutated heavily, and hence it may not be good design to use them for hashing/comparison.  Strings on the other hand are immutable.  Seems these are just meant to be containers for Strings with added functionality.

Comment: you should have added s1.toString().equals(s2.toString()) into examples :) upd: and just as I write...

Comment: Thanks @Sarief.  Added.

Comment: also `s1.compareTo(s2) == 0`